# How to stop thread from execution if certain condition is met

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, executorservice, java.util.concurrent

Say I have a service that tries to load the data from DB, if data does not exist in DB, It tries to load from master DB and if it is not found there as well it will try to fetch from another API.

This is a business requirement given by the client for loading the data.

How we can reduce the response time of my rest endpoint in a worst-case scenario?

I am trying to use an executor service framework to spawn multiple threads to run asynchronoulsy, but I don't know how to stop the execution of the remaining threads if one of the threads returns the successful response(loads data). Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried Thread.stop() method?

Comment: @Roophie according to [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()), method `stop()`, in class `Thread`, is deprecated (since Java 1.2 which was released in 1998). In other words method `stop()` has been deprecated for over 20 years.

Comment: @Abra: Is there any other way I can stop the execution of the thread?Is there any other alternative approach to improve the overall performance of the API ?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you bother?  Presumably, the latency in all of these threads is going to be waiting for an external interface to respond, right?  So by the time you've had an answer back from one of them, the other two should have already dispatched their external calls and are waiting for a response - there's probably next to zero impact on the performance of your system in killing off the slower threads.  Just let them complete and ignore their responses.

Comment: ^^^^^ exactly what I thought - the other two threads are already out of the gate, so locking the stable door is pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you [submit](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#submit(java.lang.Runnable)) a task to an `ExecutorService`, it returns you a `Future`.
Just call [`cancel​()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel(boolean)) method of the `Future`. From the docs:

> Attempts to cancel execution of this task. This attempt will fail if the task has already completed, has already been cancelled, or could not be cancelled for some other reason. If successful, and this task has not started when cancel is called, this task should never run. If the task has already started, then the mayInterruptIfRunning parameter determines whether the thread executing this task should be interrupted in an attempt to stop the task.

Comment: For calling the cancel method i have to check which thread has actually returned the object(using get method).Then additional conditonal checks are required to call the cancel method for remaining threads.Since all the calls are asynchronous,till the time i cancel the execution of any thread,thread will already complete its job.Please correct me if i am wrong